# Orbit Space of Moduli Space in Morse Homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology, morse-theory

If I have a group $G$ acting on a topological space $X$, and this action is free (no fixed points), what can I say about the orbit space $X/G$?

I am aware that freeness plus proper discontinuity leads to a result regarding quotient maps and covering spaces. This is not what my question is about.

My particular inquiry has to do with [arXiv:1701.02293](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02293). The set of points of $M$
that belong to a flow trajectory of $−$grad$(f)$ that join $p$ to $q$, $M(f ; p, q)$, admits a natural action of $\mathbb{R}$ (by translations). On p.6-7 Pedroza says "The action is in fact free and the orbit space of this action is denoted by $\hat{M}(f ; p, q)$. Hence $\hat{M}(f ; p, q)$ is identified as the space of trajectories that joint $p$ to $q$."

But this has generated confusion for me. It seems that Pedroza is saying that freeness implies that we can make some sort of identification, but I do not see what this identification is or why we can say that.

Is it true in general that when an action is free, $X$ can be identified (homotopy equivalent, homeomorphic?) with $X/G$? I doubt this is true.

If not, what is a sufficient condition for $X$ to be, say, homotopy equivalent with its orbit space under some action?

Answer (score 1):

In the notation of the article, the quotient space $\hat{M}(f;p,q)$ is the space of trajectories in the sense that a point of it corresponds to a unique trajectory in $M(f;p,q)\subset M$, concretely , its pre-image under the quotient map.

Comment: When you say "corresponds," this is exactly the word I do not understand here. Is the fact that a point of $\hat{M}(f;p,q)$ "corresponds to a unique trajectory" in $M(f;p,q)$ because when the action is free, all the images $g(x)$ are distinct? When I think "correspondence" I think "bijection." What is in bijection with what?

Comment: If you have any action of a group $G$ on a set $X$, then $X/G$ 'is' the set of orbits of the action, by definition. A more loose way of phrasing it is that it is a space whose points corresponds bijectively to the orbits of the action and there is a map $X\to X/G$ with the property that the pre-image of a point is its corresponding orbit. By construction, the orbits of the action in question are certain trajectories. Freeness helps towards the fact the quotient space is a manifold of one lower dimension. But it's not necessary for the "being an orbit-space"-bit.